# What tripod is this? Can you recommend something similar or better?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, tripod

I was reading the recently released [review of the Canon EF-S 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS II](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Canon-EF-S-18-55mm-f-3.5-5.6-IS-II-Lens-Review.aspx) over at The Digital Picture, and really liked the neat little tripod used for the example shots. The head is the [Acratech GV2 Ballhead](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Acratech-GV2-Ballhead-Review.aspx), but I can't figure out the legs.

Does anyone know what tripod this is? Do you have something similar (or better) to recommend?

[image: camera and tripod]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a Really Right Stuff tripod; I think it's the [Ground Level Tripod](http://reallyrightstuff.com/ProductDesc.aspx?code=TP-243&type=0&eq=&desc=TP-243-Ground-Level-Tripod&key=it).

Comment: Awesome! thanks. They really do look like exactly what I need, and I know RRS makes nice gear.

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked for 'something better', I have to recommend the Gorillapod SLR Zoom by Joby.

Great for travel, and can handle a 5D2 (sans grip) and a 24-105.

[Amazon Linky](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000KFRSG4)

Comment: I don't know about "better", but it's certainly a bit different. Thanks for the link. I've always been skeptical about those being strong enough to hold a larger lens/camera combo. Thanks for the feedback. It's certainly a lot cheaper.

Comment: Ah the product image doesn't to that tripod justice. These two are very different classifications. Looking at RRS's web page, the tripod is actually quite a bit larger.

Answer (score 1):

It's nice but you can get much the same effect with any tripod without the legs extended and with the center column either removed or not down the center.

Most tripods allow you to splay legs at just about any angle.

If you were going to be wanting to use a tripod in this way all the time though, that would be a great tripod for the job.

Comment: Yeah, I've got a tripod that'll do the splayed leg thing, but I'm still in the market for something sized like this. The specific reason is that I do a fair bit of indoor shooting (with people/customers around) where I don't have the luxury of taking up that much room. I'm currently handholding a lot of these shots, which is far from ideal in a dark environment.

Comment: It sure sounds like this would be a great option then.  I have a Really Right Stuff plate on my tripod head and love it.  They make great gear.

Answer (score 1):

There are also the tablet tripods like this one.

http://www.manfrotto.com/product_list/8374.58969.76910.0.0/Table_Tripods

They can have and extention that make it taller. I always have one of this in my bag.